# Where are the files stored in Hue in Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, hue

If I go to the hue link here at `http://ec2-****:8888/hue/home/` I can access the hue dashboard and create and save files etc. However, I'm not able to see those files while browsing through the system using SSH. Where are these files stored in the system?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching form them? `sudo find / -name "test1.sql"`?

Comment: I actually did, but results came in empty :/

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it works Alex, you cannot see that information in your filesystem.

Hue is giving you a view of the underlying Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS).

The information in this filesystem is spread across several nodes in your Hadoop cluster.

If you need to find something in that filesystem, you cannot use the typical file manipulation tools provided by the operating system, but their Hadoop counterparts.

For your use case, Hadoop provide you the `hdfs dfs` command, or equivalently, `hadoop fs`.

Let's say you wanna find `test1.sql` in the Hadoop filesystem. You can issue the following command once you ssh in your node:

```sh
hadoop fs -ls -R / | grep test1.sql
```

Or:

```sh
hadoop fs -find / -name test1.sql
```

Please, see the [complete reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) of the options available.

You can retrieve the file to your local filesystem, once located by the previous commands, by issuing the following one:

```sh
hadoop fs -get /path/to/test1.sql test1.sql
```

This operation could be also achieved from the Hue File Browser.

In the specific case of Amazon EMR, this distributed filesystem can be supported by different [storage systems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html) basically, HDFS, for ephemeral workloads, and EMRFS, an implementation of HDFS over S3:

> EMRFS is an implementation of the Hadoop file system used for reading and writing regular files from Amazon EMR directly to Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jccampanero, however, I've searched both my file system and the hadoop file system (using the commands above), but I cannot find the file. I suspect it's actually not stored as a file, but just represented as one in the GUI, but I wanted to see if there is a way I can download this, etc

Comment: I don't think I got the answer that I was looking for, but thanks for the well researched answer, hence awarding the bounty. Would love it if you have more details on this

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Alex, and thank you for the bounty. Regarding your comments, as I indicated in the answer, Hue is giving you a view of the underlying HDFS filesystem. You are right, in this file system, you will not find the files as you are used to in a traditional operating system, but it is not important, in fact, this kind of filesystem is not conceived to look for files in this way, but for distributed processing (m/r,...), storage (hbase,...), etc. In any case, if you need to interact with HDFS in that way, you need to use the tools that Hadoop provide for that task as indicated

Comment: If you want to delve into Hue, I recommend you take the course [Take Control of Your Big Data with HUE in Cloudera CDH](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/big-data-hue-cloudera-cdh) of Xavier Morera in Pluralsight, or [this other one](https://www.coursera.org/learn/cloud-storage-big-data-analysis-sql) from Cloudera on Coursera: please, be aware that I am not related with any learning platform, I am talking only about learning resources that helped me to understand how this stuff works. I hope it helps. Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you think I can be of any help.

Comment: You are welcome @AlexJoseph! Let me know if you need anything else.